Is there any method to do query with spring data dynamoDB
Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: Non-expression parameters: {ScanFilter} Expression parameters: {ProjectionExpression} (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: c47379cc-100a-45d0-9ed9-ebd8ba629583; Proxy: null)
I want to create a query like this:
@Query("SELECT d FROM Deployment d " +
    "WHERE d.id IN (" +
    "SELECT MAX(d2.id) FROM Deployment d2 " +
    "WHERE d2.environmentId = d.environmentId " +
    "AND d2.status = 'success' " +
    "GROUP BY d2.environmentId )")

I work with spring boot 3.2.4, spring-data-dynamodb 5.2.5, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb 1.12.707.
